# How to Control what Ace Editor Autocompleter writes to the File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, ace-editor

I am using react-ace editor to allow users to enter Scala code on a website. I’ve also defined an autocompleter for it. Right now, when users accept a suggestion from the autocompleter for a function, the autocompleter pastes the entire function signature into the file, substituting the function’s parameters’ names for the arguments, which is unhelpful and annoying for users.

I would like the autocompleter to instead do the following: when the user accepts a suggestion for a function, just paste in the name of the function and an open parenthesis. Then, the autocompleter should show the user a list of the parameters of the function, both their names and their types (i.e. `param1: type1, param2: type2, …`), but not paste them in if the user hits enter. As a stretch goal I’d like it to bold the positional parameter the user is currently typing out an argument for. The behavior I want is inspired by IDE’s like IntelliJ or Visual Studio that do just that.

Is there a way to do anything like this in the react-ace editor?

Answer (score 2):

Ace autocompleter items can have value snippet and caption properties. `caption` is what is going to be shown in the popup value is what is going to be inserted when user presses enter. snippet is an alternative to value which is a textmate style snippet allowing to specify position of cursor after selecting text.

In this case you can return an item like

```
{value: "funcName", caption: "funcName(x, y, z)"}
```

or

```
{snippet: "funcName($0)", caption: "funcName(x, y, z)"}
```

or even `snippet: "funcName(${1:paramName1}, ${2:paramName2})$0"` to allow user to tab through parameters.

Just make sure to return `\$` and `\\` in the snippet if you want them to appear as literal `$` and `\`.

As for the second part of showing parameter types, and not inserting them, it is not done by autocompleter, it is done by tooltip which is not built in to the ace yet. Here is how it is implemented in cloud9 ide https://github.com/c9/core/blob/master/plugins/c9.ide.language.core/tooltip.js

Comment: As to your last point, could I imitate the desired behavior by having value be an empty string?

Comment: the way popup is opened and keybindings it has are quite different, so even though you can do it, it will not work well